# Which #includes in main.cpp should I use (LNK2005 already defined)

Tags: c++, include, lnk2005

I have the following classes:

// Buffer.cpp

```
#include "MonoSample.h"
#include "Buffer.h"

#define INBUFFERSIZEBLOCK   1024                // input block size
#define MAXBUFFERSIZE       1000000             // max buffer size (1MB)

#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

using std::endl;
using std::fstream;


Buffer::Buffer()
{
}
(...)
```

// Buffer.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using std::string;

typedef struct  WAV_HEADER              
{    
uint8_t         RIFF[4];    
uint32_t        ChunkSize;    
uint8_t         WAVE[4];    
uint8_t         fmt[4];    
uint32_t        Subchunk1Size;      
uint16_t        audioFormat;            
uint16_t        numOfChan;          
uint32_t        samplesPerSec;    
uint32_t        bytesPerSec;
uint16_t        blockAlign;    
uint16_t        bitsPerSample;    
uint8_t         Subchunk2ID[4];    
uint32_t        sampledDataLen;    
} wavHdr, *pwavHdr;


class Buffer
{

private:
    string         wFileNamePath;                   
    int                  nChannel;                  
    wavHdr                  head;                   
    unsigned long     samplesLen;                   
    unsigned long     samplesPte;               
    FILE*                wavFile;               
    MonoSample*      firstSample;       

public:

    Buffer();
    Buffer(string filePath, int id);    
    ~Buffer();

    wavHdr              getHeader();    // retorna el header del fitxer wav
    string         getWavFileName();    // retorna el nom del fitxer wav
    int                     getNumChannel();    // retorna el id del fitxer wav
    bool              ResetBuffer();    // inicia el bufer
    void              closeBuffer();    // allibera la memoria del buffer
    bool  openFile(string p, int n);    // obre fitxer
    MonoSample*    getFirstSample();    // punter a la primera mostra mono  
    MonoSample*    getSample(int n);    // pointer to 16 bits of the mono sample n
};
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "Buffer.cpp"
#include "MonoSample.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

#define NUMCANALS 16

int main()
{
(...)
}
```

When I run my program I get the following errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: class MonoSample * __cdecl Buffer::getSample(int)" (?getSample@Buffer@@QEAAPEAVMonoSample@@H@Z) already defined in Buffer.obj

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: class MonoSample * __cdecl Buffer::getFirstSample(void)" (?getFirstSample@Buffer@@QEAAPEAVMonoSample@@XZ) already defined in Buffer.obj

(...)

I think it is due the fact that in the main.cpp I write #include "Buffer.cpp" but I don't know how to do it without that #include... How can I use Buffer objects if I don't have this #include?

Thank you!

Comment: You are right about where the problem is. Include `buffer.h` instead of `buffer.cpp`? A .cpp file needs only the declaration of types/functions, the definition can be in a separate file.

Comment: @DeiDei: He probably wants the *definitions* of the types - but just the *declarations* of functions.  (Which is what the header gives.  A declaration of WAV_HEADER would look like `struct WAV_HEADER;`.)

Comment: You don't need to declare WAV_HEADER - you need to define it (by #including buffer.h).

Answer (score 3):

Main should start

```
#include "Buffer.h"
```

So that it has the definition of the class (but not the definition of all the member functions).  You almost *never* want to #include .cpp files.

This will produce further errors because you use types in Buffer.h that you haven't defined there.  The fix for this is to define them by putting

```
#include "MonoSample.h"
```

at the start of Buffer.h.

Comment: I would say *never* include .cpp files. *"Almost"* adds a lot of meaning to it.

Comment: There are advanced preprocessor techniques which involve included source files.  One approach is to call them .inl files.  Another is to call them .cpp (which means your editor understands them).

Comment: Thanks @MartinBonner

When I change #include "Buffer.h" instead of "Buffer.cpp" I get lots of errors of my Buffer.h class: Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '' Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '' Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

What should I do?

Comment: @crende: `#include "MonoSample.h"` in Buffer.h, which uses that type.

Comment: @MartinBonner thank you!!

Do I need to add also struct WAV_HEADER in the private atributs of the declaration of Buffer class in Buffer.h ?

Comment: @crende: No.  `wavHdr header;` is just another (shorter) way of saying `struct WAV_HEADER header;` (or `WAV_HEADER header;`), and you already have that.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is due the fact that in the main.cpp I write #include "Buffer.cpp"

Yes.

> I don't know how to do it without that #include... How can I use Buffer objects if I don't have this #include?

Your Visual Studio project has "main.cpp" and "Buffer.cpp" in it. The two are *linked* together during build. C++ typically has a two-phase build process: first *compilation*, then *linking*.

As long as your "main.cpp" knows about `Buffer` and `WAV_HEADER` during *compilation*, that's enough (this is what you achieve with your `#include "Buffer.h"`). Linkage takes care of the rest.

Comment: @crende: So now go ahead and resolve those problems.

Answer (score 0):

After compilation, the linker will merge the obj files . You have the same symbol defined multiple times in different translation ("One Definition Rule" violated here)
Put the definition of your class in a separate file which does not contain also the definitions of the member functions of that class; then, let buffer.cpp and main.cpp include that file .

Comment: #include<cstdint>